# What's a good variety of decorative grass for indoors and balcony?

Tags: grass, variety-selection, urban-gardening

I'm looking for the right variety of grass which would thrive in a pot in a well lit living room and in an open balcony. Two different types, one indoor and one outdoor will be fine, too.

My main requirement is considerable height when full grown - something between 50 and 80 cm (20" to 35"). A big and deep pot is no problem, it would even be welcome. I'd love if the indoor variety would keep its greens all year round. There would be no problem moving the outdoor pots indoors off season.

In the house we keep the temperature around 22°C, we live in central Europe, so the summer temperatures outdoors oscillate between 10°C on cold nights and sometimes more than 30°C on hot summer afternoons. Winter gets us sometimes well below zero. The balcony is exposed to some wind, but there are plenty of possibilites to limit its impact through various screens.

Something like this, but in a pot:

[image: Decorative grass]

If there is anything to add, I'll happiy edit that in, just drop a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My ID would be Miscanthus gracillimus.  Maiden grass, I always thought it was maidenhair grass.  Eulalia is also another name for the genus.
[miscanthus gracillimus](http://www.finegardening.com/eulalia-grass-miscanthus-sinensis-gracillimus)

The balcony would be just fine.  This guy needs lots of light and indoors just won't work unless you add artificial lighting.  Use large pots, great drainage and always when planting in pots, use sterilized potting soil.  Osmocote extended release fertilizer.  Great privacy...cut it back to a foot in the spring.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll look at it! Artificial lighting may be the thing actually, since it could be installed pretty easily in my living room.

Comment: This isn't miscanthus (look at the seedheads).

Comment: @J.Musser I went out to look and by golly I was seeing Miscanthus with those seed heads.  What do you think this grass is?

Comment: @Pavel  No matter the ID, grass will need artificial lighting!  Definitely easy to install and not that expensive.  These ornamental grasses would be stunning especially if you kept a mono culture of sorts!  That fine vertical texture works very well with architectural environments!  Perhaps adding a few other plants...such as Crocosmia?  Yellow or red, with the same texture yet arching and color would be fun. Something to drip over the edges such ipomeia sweet potato vine in chartreuse?

Comment: Protect your pots on your balcony with burlap and christmas tree lights...not the LED type.  Wrap the entire plant with the lights and then wrap with burlap.  Works well for your zone.

Comment: @stormy Thank you for the additional tips, I'm already on with the artificial lighting (a friend of mine is really keen diyer in that direction and will help me out). The combination with other plants will come once I'm confident I'm on good terms with the grass itself :)